# in Pandas how to get a UTC TimeStamp (at a given hour) from a DateTime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a variable in my dataframe that looks like

```
Day
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
```

I would like to generate a time variable that gives me the **UTC timestamp** of the corresponding **EST timestamp** of the day in **Day** at 9:00 am in the morning (always 9am, dont ask why...).

Precisely, considering the output for row one,I mean going from `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-01 9:00 EST` to `2015-01-01 14:00 UTC`. How can I do that in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats probably the better solution

```
df['time']=df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x + ' 9:00')
df['time_utc']=df['time'].apply(lambda x: `pd.Timestamp(x).tz_localize('US/Eastern').tz_convert('UTC'))`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.Day = pd.date_range('1/1/2015 09:00', periods=10, freq='D')
df.Day = df.Day.tz_localize('UTC')
df.Day_converted = df.Day.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

After creating the timeseries you can localize it to a zone with .tz_localize and then convert it.

Comment: yes thanks but the day has to come from the Day variable, not hard coded in the code!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do it with individual variables:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

ts = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01')    # Going from 2015-01-01 to ...
ts = ts + timedelta(hours=9)       # 2015-01-01 9:00 ...
ts = ts.tz_localize('US/Eastern')  # EST to 
ts = ts.tz_convert('UTC')          # 2015-01-01 14:00 UTC
```